# Consume RabbitMQ hosted on Cloud Foundry externally via websocket

Tags: rabbitmq, cloud-foundry

My question actually contains 2 questions:
Is it possible to install the RabbitMQ Web-Stomp Plugin on Cloud Foundry?
Can I consume the the RabbitMQ queue hosted on cloud foundry from an external service?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It depends. The *RabbitMQ for Pivotal Cloud Foundry* version of the service [allows WebStomp to be enabled](http://docs.pivotal.io/rabbitmq-cf/1-7-0/configuring.html). But you could be using RabbitMQ bundled by someone else, so it'll depend on which version you're using.

You could consume the service from outside of Cloud Foundry, providing the service instance is started somewhere you can get TCP access to. It might not be a great idea though, as your off-Cloud Foundry consumer has no knowledge of any changes that happen through the Cloud Foundry service management lifecycle - what if the instance gets deleted or updated?